# Is there a way to specify the pivot table for a has many relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, has-many

I have a Company model that has a relationship with users. I have a pivot table called game_user generated with https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended by doing `php artisan make:migration:pivot companies users` . I have the following migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('company_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('company_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['company_id', 'user_id']);
    });
}
```

On my Company Model I made a employees function for the relationship

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

And on my CompanyController I have the following

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Company;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CompanyController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        return Company::find($id);
    }

    public function employees($id)
    {
        return Company::find($id)->employees;
    }
}
```

But when requesting to it from postman with a get request.

http://localhost/laravel_applications/myapi/public/api/company/1/employees

I get a 500 internal server error. Shouldn't Laravel automatically detect the table? I'm quite sure it isn't detecting or even looking for my pivot table.

This is my route, I tested it by returning as string and that worked just fine. So the route is working.

```
Route::get('company/{id}/employees', 'CompanyController@employees');
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `hasMany` should be used for one-to-many relation. You need to call `belongsToMany` method for a many-to-many relation.